# How to use a flag to restart an action in a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried using a volatile boolean to act as a flag to stop/start/restart the action in the thread, however it does not work. It just keeps on going forever and never terminates. Any help on how to properly do this or why my code does not work will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class thread {

    public static int i = 0;
    private static Thread print = null;
    private static printThread runnable = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runnable = new printThread();
        print = new Thread (runnable);
        print.start();

        System.out.println("Starting");
        runnable.begin();
        if(i > 5)
        {
            runnable.terminate();
        }

        i = 10;
        runnable.begin();
        if(i > 15)
        {
            runnable.terminate();
        }
    }

    public static final void print()
    {
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }

    public static final class printThread implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean running = false;

        public void terminate() {
            running = false;
        }

        public void begin() {
            running = true;
        }

        public boolean isRunning() {
            return running;
        }

        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                if(running)
                {
                    print();
                }

                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is rather vague. Please edit your question to expand on the expected behavior of the program. And you should really inform yourself about [concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: It can be that `terminate()` is never called. E.g., main function has executed its body before `i` becomes 5.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `while` loop execution never ends. You could introduce 2 states: terminated and waiting to simulate threads start/pause/restart/stop. However, even if you pause the Thread it will be running, just different branch of code will be executed inside while loop.

Please, see the code snippet below

```
public static final class printThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean waiting = false;
    private volatile boolean terminated = false;


    public void terminate() {
        terminated = true;
    }

    public void pause() {
        waiting = true;
    }

    public void restart() {
        waiting = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!terminated) {
            if(waiting) {
                //the thread is paused
            } else {
                //the thread is running
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> however it does not work. It just keeps on going forever and never terminates.

In your `run()` method of your thread, you aren't watching for the value of your  `volatile boolean running` field.  It probably should be something like:

```
    public void run() {
        while(!running) {
            print();
            // you might want a short Thread.sleep(10); here to stop the spinning
        }
    }
```

However, as @Anton points out, once your thread terminates, it can't be restarted without some other flag.  See his answer.

Also, you are sharing `i` between the main thread and the your printing thread.  That also needs to be `volatile` so it can be properly shared.  Since you are incrementing it in multiple threads, you should use an `AtomicInteger` for that.

```
 public static AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
 ...
 if (i.get() > 5) ...
 ...
 i.set(10);
 ...
 i.incrementAndGet();
```

Couple of other comments:

- Be careful of `static` fields.  `print` and `runnable` should be defined only inside of the `main(...)` method to restrict access.
- Classes should begin with an uppercase letter so it should be `PrintThread`.
- Actually, because `PrintThread` isn't a thread, it should be `PrintRunnable` or maybe even better, `Printer`.